# Integrating websocket at React client

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, express, websocket

I am trying to connect a backend layer running on localhost, below is the source code:

```
const { createServer } = require("http");

const cors = require("cors");

const photos = require("./photos");

const app = require("express")();
const WebSocket = require("ws");

app.use(cors());

app.get("/", (req, res) => {
  res.status(200).json({});
});

app.get("/photos", (req, res) => {
  res.status(200).json({ photos });
});

const clients = new Set();

app.post("/photos/:id", (req, res) => {
  const photo = photos.find((p) => {
    return p.id === req.params.id;
  });

  photo.status= "PENDING";
  // Send back an approval
  const timeout = (3 + Math.floor(Math.random() * 4)) * 1000;
  setTimeout(() => {
    photo.status = "APPROVED";
    clients.forEach((ws) => {
      ws.send(JSON.stringify({ event: "APPROVED", photo }));
    });
  }, timeout);
  res.status(200).json({ photo });
});

const port = process.env.PORT || 3001;
const server = createServer(app);
server.listen(port, () => {
  console.log(`Starting server on port ${port}`);
});

const wss = new WebSocket.Server({ path: "/ws", server });
wss.on("connection", (ws) => {
  clients.add(ws);
  console.log("WebSocket connection established");

  ws.on("close", () => {
    clients.delete(ws);
    console.log("WebSocket connection closed");
  });
});
```

As on react client we can't use "ws" so I tried using both "websocket" package but I am not able to connect to "http" as it is not supported. Below is the source code:

```
import React from "react";
 import { w3cwebsocket as W3CWebSocket } from "websocket";

 const client = new W3CWebSocket('http://localhost:3001/ws');
// const client = new W3CWebSocket('ws://localhost:3001');

function App() {

  React.useEffect(
    () => {
      client.onopen = () => {
        console.log('WebSocket Client Connected');
      };
      client.onmessage = (message) => {
        console.log(message);
      };
    }, []
  )
     return null
}
```

Need help at client level to connect to 'http://localhost:3001/ws' to establish and listen connection.

Comment: If you have no a lot understanding of sockets (like me), I suggest to use socket.io package => https://www.npmjs.com/package/socket.io    It's a wrapper for websockets.

Comment: Yes but it is a two way thing but I don't want to change the server code, just need to add the code on client side.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76810467/failed-to-connect-to-websocket-server-running-inside-a-container-from-inside-of Is there some obvious issue here

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are connecting to the wrong url. In following line on the server, you specify a path as `/ws` .

`const wss = new WebSocket.Server({ path: "/ws", server });`

So you need to connect to the specified path.

`const client = new W3CWebSocket('ws://localhost:3001/ws');`

If you remove the `path: "/ws"` from your `createServer`, the url `ws://localhost:3001` (notice, no `/ws` path.. )should also work as expected.

Here's an example which worked on my machine ( without react, it's for showing socket connection.)

##### Client

```js
var W3CWebSocket = require('websocket').w3cwebsocket;

const client = new W3CWebSocket('ws://localhost:3001/ws');

client.onopen = () => {
    console.log('WebSocket Client Connected');
};

client.onmessage = (message) => {
    console.log(message);
};
client.onerror = function() {
    console.log('Connection Error');
};
```

##### Server

```js
const { createServer } = require("http");

const cors = require("cors");

const app = require("express")();
const WebSocket = require("ws");

app.use(cors());

const port = process.env.PORT || 3001;
const server = createServer(app);

server.listen(port, () => {
  console.log(`Starting server on port ${port}`);
});
const wss = new WebSocket.Server({ path: "/ws", server });
wss.on("connection", (ws) => {
  console.log("WebSocket connection established");

  ws.on("close", () => {
    console.log("WebSocket connection closed");
  });
});
```