# Failed to connect to Websocket server running inside a container from inside of another container

Tags: node.js, reactjs, typescript, docker, websocket

I have a component rabbit-receiver which reads from a rabbitmq exchange, sets up a Websocket server and pushes the message into the Websocket server.

```
const RABBITMQ_URL = process.env.RABBITMQ_URL || "amqp://localhost";

// Set up WebSocket server
const wss = new WebSocket.Server({ port: 5050 });

(async () => {
  try {
    const connection = await amqp.connect(RABBITMQ_URL);
    const channel = await connection.createChannel();

    process.once("SIGINT", async () => {
      await channel.close();
      await connection.close();
    });

    await channel.assertExchange(exchange, "fanout", { durable: false });

    const { queue: tempQueue } = await channel.assertQueue("", { exclusive: true });
    await channel.bindQueue(tempQueue, exchange, "");

    await channel.consume(tempQueue, (message) => {
      if (message) {
        const content = message.content.toString();
        console.log(" [x] Received '%s'", content);
        
        // Broadcast the message to all connected WebSocket clients
        wss.clients.forEach((client) => {
          if (client.readyState === WebSocket.OPEN) {
            client.send(content);
          }
        });
      }
    }, { noAck: true });

    console.log(" [*] Waiting for messages. To exit press CTRL+C");
  } catch (err) {
    console.warn(err);
  }
})();
```

I have another React UI implementation which is meant to listen to this Websocket and display these notifications.

```
useEffect(() => {
    const ws = new WebSocket("ws://rabbit-receiver:5050");

    ws.onmessage = (event) => {
      console.log("SearchKeyword: came in here")
      const message = event.data;
      setMessages((prevMessages) => [...prevMessages, message]);
      // Show WebSocket messages as notifications
      toast(message, { autoClose: false });
    };
```

I have both of these services running on separate docker composes as they are part of other group of services but they are in the same network so as to .

```
version: '3'
services:
  hardware-reservation-ui:
    image: hardware-reservation-ui
    ports:
      - "3000:3000"
    networks:
      - hardware_reservation_net
networks:
  hardware_reservation_net:
    external: true
```

```
version: '3'

services:
  rabbit-receiver:
    build: .
    ports:
      - "5050:5050"
    networks:
      - hardware_reservation_net
networks:
  hardware_reservation_net:
    external: true
```

When I inspect the UI I see that it mentions
`"WebSocket connection to 'ws://rabbit-receiver:5050/' failed:"`

However, if I exec into the hardware-reservation-ui container and do
`websocat ws://rabbit-receiver:5050`

Then it starts listening to the Websocket server.

Comment: Please, double-check your docker-compose network definition. In the example you provided, you typed the network name with dashes somewhere and underscores somewhere else:

1. hardware-reservation_net
2. hardware_reservation_net

Comment: That was a typo in the post itself. I have fixed it now. However I was able to connect now with a different client.

var W3CWebSocket = require('websocket').w3cwebsocket;
const client = new W3CWebSocket('ws://localhost:5050');